# What is the earliest version of GhostScript that is Windows 10 compatible?

Tags: windows-10, ghostscript.net

What is the earliest version of Ghostscript that is compatible to run on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

All 32-bit or 64-bit Windows versions of Ghostscript run on Windows 10.

You should use the most recent version (currently 9.27), versions prior to 9.27 have security vulnerabilities which have been fixed, and have been exploited in the past.